# Why is $(b-Ax)^T(b-Ax) = (b^Tb - 2b^T Ax + x^T A^T Ax)$?

Tags: linear-algebra

Why is it true that
$$
(b-Ax)^T(b-Ax) = (b^Tb - b^T Ax - b^T Ax + x^T A^T Ax)
$$
Shouldn't it be
$$
(b-Ax)^T(b-Ax) = (b^Tb - b^T Ax - x^T A^T b + x^T A^T Ax)
$$?

So in why are there *two* $b^T Ax$? This must mean that $x^T A^T b = b^T Ax$. If true, why can you assume that? $b$ is a $M \times 1$ vector, $x$ is a $N \times 1$ vector, and $A$ is a $M \times N$ matrix.

Comment: Basically (and oversimplifying a bit), because it's just a number. More specifically, it's a $1\times1$ matrix whose transpose is itself.

Answer (score 3):

It is true since $a^{T}b = b^{T}a$ (dot product is commutative). Simply take $a=Ax$.

Answer (score 1):

I assume you are using vectors from $ \mathbb{R}^n $. In real euclidian spaces the scalar product is symmetric. So here you have $ x^T\cdot A^T\cdot b=(A\cdot x)^T\cdot b=\langle A\cdot x, b \rangle=\langle b,A\cdot x \rangle = b^T\cdot A\cdot x$

Answer (score 1):

Let $A=\left(\begin{matrix}-A_1^T-\\-A_2^T-\\...\\-A_M^T-\end{matrix}\right)$

$b^TAx=\left(\begin{matrix}b_1&b_2&...&b_M\end{matrix}\right)\left(\begin{matrix}A_1^Tx\\A_2^Tx\\...\\A_M^Tx\end{matrix}\right)=\sum_{j=1}^Mb_jA_j^Tx$

$x^TA^Tb=x^T\left(\begin{matrix}|&|&&|\\A_1&A_2&...&A_M\\|&|&&|\end{matrix}\right)\left(\begin{matrix}b_1\\b_2\\...\\b_M\end{matrix}\right)=\left(\begin{matrix}x^TA_1&x^TA_2&...&x^TA_M\end{matrix}\right)\left(\begin{matrix}b_1\\b_2\\...\\b_M\end{matrix}\right)=\sum_{j=1}^Mx^TA_jb_j$

But $x^TA_j=A_j^Tx$. Further, $b_jA_j^Tx=A_j^Txb_j$ as this is multiplying two scalars.

---

Alternatively, $b^TAx=b^T(Ax)=b^Ta=(b^Ta)^T=a^Tb=x^TA^Tb$